# PC as W-LAN router

Tags: wireless-networking

In our office we only have network via cable, but my Windows 7 or 8.1 PC also has WLAN antennas. Is it possible to install some drivers turning the PC into a WLAN router, so my smartphone can access the network, too?

Comment: You shouldn't need any additional software or drivers assuming your PC is properly configured and has the necessary software running (like a DHCP or internet connection sharing enabled). The specifics depend on the operating system though.

Comment: what is OS and version on your PC?

Comment: Yes, there are. But maybe talk to your admin first if there is any. Most likely there are reasons, why he didn't set up some WLAN for mobile devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to setup a WiFi access point:

- Open a command prompt as admin (cmd)
- Run `netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=your_network_name key=your_password`
- Run `netsh wlan start hostednetwork`

Then enable connection sharing:

- Run `ncpa.cpl` to open the adapters list
- Select your internet adapter, right click, properties
- Under the Sharing tab, check "Allow other network users..."
- Finally select the wifi adaper and hit Ok

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows you can use Internet Connection Sharing. Go to the properties of the LAN interface, sharing Tab and enable the checkbox "Allow other network users to connect through this computer’s Internet connection".

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/using-internet-connection-sharing#1TC=windows-7

Answer (score 0):

At [tomshardware.co.uk](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/38835-42-create-virtual-wifi-router-internet-windows) I found following steps (similar to Nicolas' answer):

- run from an admin command prompt `netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=<nice name> key=<sensible password> keyUsage=persistent` (the password needs to be at least 8 characters long)
- in the control panel' *Network and Sharing center* click *change adapter settings*
- there should be a nice entry now with "Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter" - rename it to something better, e.g. "LAN-shared-over-WLAN"
- open the properties of the LAN-network connection, switch to the *Sharing* tab, select the "LAN-shared-over-WLAN" from the combobox, then check the "Allow other network users to connect through this computer's Internet connection" checkbox
- run at the admin command prompt: `netsh wlan start hostednetwork`
- to stop, run `netsh wlan start hostednetwork`
- to remove the "LAN-shared-over-WLAN" entry again, run `netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=disallow`